# CameraUI save twice Pictures(adobe air)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, android-camera

I have a problem, that is
How to solve the problem of the picture generated twice?(in camera Roll)

Everything is working fine. But for some reason the gallery always saves two of the same shot. I can not find the reason.
and this is my code, thanks

```
   var cameraUI : CameraUI = new CameraUI();     //cameraUI
   b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onb1);  //camera btn

   function onb1(e: MouseEvent) : void
   {
      if(CameraUI.isSupported) 
       {
           cameraUI.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try removing the COMPLETE listeners when the image loads:

```
function onImageLoaded(e: Event) : void
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);

    if(bitmap != null) {removeChild(bitmap);}   
    bitmapData = Bitmap(e.target.content).bitmapData;
    bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    addChild(bitmap), addChild(b1);// addchild
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still the same

Comment: I simplify the code, the problem is "cameraUI.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);"

Comment: use cameraUI.launch(MediaType.IMAGE); picture generated twice